# Subscription. NotificationURL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

i'm about to finish a task, but i have a question about the notificationUrl in my subscription to Microsoft Graph

```
var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();
            var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
            sub.ChangeType = "created";
            **sub.NotificationUrl = "`***https://878786868.ngrok.io***`/api/NWebHookPostSubscription";**
            sub.Resource = "/users/*my-email/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages";
            sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
            sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";
```

i'm using ngrok and you can use ngrok just for two hours i think, so someone knows if there's a way that the url never expire? greetings

Comment: Sure, get a paid subscription for Ngrok https://ngrok.com/pricing

Comment: and excuse me but if i want to notificationUrl never expire do i need to pay ngrok or is there other options?

Comment: No idea, you better ask them I suppose

Comment: It doesn't have to be paid to be time unlimited.  It can be a free account, but you have to sign up for an account and use the associated authtoken when starting your tunnel.